# JS Fetch: How to return response with body or error?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am struggling with this code moving from ajax to fetch. I want to call an API and

- not return until done
- return the response object with status
- return the response object with json
- return the response object with an error message if exists
  This code is returning prior to completion causing an uncaught error, and forcing the browser to repaint (Chrome). I am unable to figure out why. If I step through the code slowly it always completes.

```
    function getAPI(url, requestOptions) {
    return fetch(url, requestOptions).then((response) => {
        return response.json().then(json => {
            response.json = json;
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            response.error = error;
            return response;
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);         
        response.error = error;
        return response;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need two catches. --- _"not return until done"_ - this already happens. --- I think the `then(json =>` function might be unnecessary. --- May you share how this function is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to get this result

```
async function getAPI(url, requestOptions) {
    let result;

    await fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => result = response)
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

    return result;
}
```

Using:

```
await getAPI('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
```

and it returns response.

//
Edited, with adding status

```
async function getAPI(url, requestOptions) {
    let result;

    await fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => result = { status: 'success', response })
        .catch(error => result = { status: 'error', error })

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If returning a promise (the `fetch`) you don't need to make the outer function `async`.

Comment: 1) In general, naming the function as getAPI is not the best option.
2) Why return a promise? This is additional code and additional steps.
3) The status can be placed in the result object, it doesn't matter whether it is success or error

The main thing is that one function fulfills its task, and does not transfer its responsibilities to other functions.

Comment: But you are returning a promise? The result variable is unneeded.

Comment: Please, read the title. "JS Fetch: How to return response with body or error?".
He needs to return response. Response and promise are different things.

Maybe I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: That will happen when `await getAPI` is used. I don't think you've misunderstood, but the code can be even simpler.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. Chrome is erroring out inside the browser code and this is aside from the problem here. I will consider this resolved.